# Single API to list all the services - consul cluster

Tags: api, consul

Is there a single API to list all the services registered in a consul cluster?

Constraint: `ui` is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends, whether you have a single datacenter or no. If yes, then you can use a [Consul HTTP API](https://www.consul.io/api/index.html) to query all the services in current agent's datacenter. Otherwise you will need to query all the datacenter names first and then query services for exact datacenter.

Here is some example from the [documentation](https://www.consul.io/api/catalog.html#list-services):

Simple request

```
curl https://consul.rocks/v1/catalog/services
```

will return the services registered in a given datacenter as follows:

```
{
  "consul": [],
  "redis": [],
  "postgresql": [
    "primary",
    "secondary"
  ]
}
```